# How to do a group by on specific rows

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am running the following query to get data back:

```
SELECT DISTINCT student_id, student_name from class_students where city = 'foobar' and student_id <> 0;
```

The data I get back looks like this:

```
 student_id |              student_name
------------+----------------------------------------
  41990     | James
  48220     | John
  00000     |
  00000     | lkjkj
  00000     | random name
  00000     | somethingelse
```

I would rather like to get this data back:

```
 student_id |              student_name
------------+----------------------------------------
  41990     | James
  48220     | John
  00000     | Name-doesnt-exist
```

Which means grouping all `00000` into one row with name `NA`

Comment: Perhaps you really just wanted `<> '00000'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT student_id, case when student_id = '00000' then 'N-A' else max(student_name) end
from class_students 
where city = 'foobar' 
  and student_id <> 0
group by student_id
```

Comment: Thanks this works. Can you please expand upon what `max` is doing here in the else clause? Also usually when I try to group by I get complained that group by needs to have same columns as select but that doesn't seem to be the case here.

Comment: @Anthony, it's basically a dummy aggregation as this function is operating on multiple rows of data. I think you'll find my answer is the general approach you need though.

Comment: @Anthony: When you group by a column then you can't just select what you want. You can select all columns you group by. All other columns you want to select need to be aggregated which means they need to be combined in any way. I use `max()` to get the highest student name for each group. In your case there is only one name for each group and multiple only once for ´00000`. If you really grasp what grouping means then you understand why you can't just select everyhting.

Answer (score 1):

If more than one name exists then flag it.

```
select student_id,
    case when count(distinct student_name) > 1 then 'N/A' else min(student_name) end as student_name
from class_students
where city = 'foobar' and student_id <> 0
group by student_id
```

Also you could eliminate these groups from the results entirely:

```
having count(distinct student_name) = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `row_number()`

```
select student_id,coalesce(student_name,'Name-doesnt-exist') as name
from
(
SELECT student_id, student_name,row_number() over(partition by student_id order by case when student_name is null then 1 else 2 end) as rn
from class_students where city = 'foobar' and student_id <> 0
)A where rn=1
```